# java persistance memory leaks

Tags: java, jpa

I have 1M rows in a mysql table and I am java persistence api when I execute following code then I get java heap error:

```
int counter = 0;
while (counter < 1000000) {
   java.util.Collection<MyEntityClass> data = myQuery.setFirstResult(counter)
       .setMaxResults(1000).getResultList();
   for(MyEntityClass obj : data){
       System.out.println(obj);
   }
   counter += 1000;
}
```

Comment: you had someone click "next" 2500 times?

Answer (score 7):

I'd wonder if JTable is really hanging onto all those old references when you click "next".  I don't believe it's a persistence problem.  Whatever backing data structure you have behind the JTable, I'd make sure that I cleared it before adding the next batch of records.  That way the old values can be GC'd.

Your JTable shouldn't have a ResultSet.  It'd be better to have a persistence tier that hid such details from clients.  Make the query for a batch of values (*not* the entire data set), load it from the ResultSet into a data structure, and close the ResultSet and Statement in a finally block.  You need to close those resources in the scope of the method in which they were created or you're asking for trouble.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend retrieving 1M rows in one go, for both memory and performance reasons. See my answer for a suggestion that you retrieve a page at a time when your user clicks next.

Comment: I"m not recommending retrieving 1M rows, either.  Do the query for the subset each time, load it into the data structure, and close.  I'll edit my question to clarify.

Answer (score 2):

- Is this a Java EE or Java SE application?
- How are you handling your entity
  manager?

The entity manager is typically associated with a context. During a transaction every entity that you recover is going to be placed in it, and it will be a cache for all entities, when the transaction commits, JPA will search for modifications in the context and commit the changes to the database.

This implies that if you recover 1 million rows you will have 1 million entities in your context, and they will not be garbage collectable until you close your entity manager.

Since you are referring to a JTable I can only assume this is a JSE application. In this type of application you are in total control of the context. In this type of application there is a one-to-one relationship between context and the entity manager (which is not always the case in Java EE environment).

This implies that you can either create an entity manager per request (i.e. transaction or conversation) or an entity manager for the entire life of the application.

If you are using the second approach, you context is never garbage collected, and the more objects you read from the database the bigger it becomes, until you may eventually reach a memory problem like the one you describe.

I am not saying this is the cause of your problem, but it could certainly be a good lead on finding the root cause, don't you think?

Comment: No mention of JPA that I can see.  If s/he's using straight JDBC, as I suspect they are, then none of this applies.

Comment: @duffymo It is on the tags of the question.

Comment: nope, I am not using jdbc directly. I have an entity class which correspond to my table.

Comment: I missed that; you're right.  @user, if you're doing straight JDBC, why the JPA tag?  I'd remove it.

Comment: But he isn't using straight JDBC, as he said above. Also in the question it does say "setFirstResult(counter).setMaxResults(1000).getResultList()" which is a hint that JPA is used.

Comment: @EdwinDalorzo: How do we choose to use entityManager per request vs application scope ? If with time we will hit memory limits with application scope why should an entity manager be kept in application scope ? We use EJB in dao:`@Stateless
@EJB(name = "java:global/Impl", beanInterface = Dao.class)
public class mpl<R> implements Dao<R> {

 @Resource(mappedName = "java:/RESOURCES")
 private DataSource ds;

 @PersistenceContext(unitName = "resources")
 EntityManager em;` will this be application scope ??

Answer (score 2):

The problem is almost certainly that your resultSet object is caching the entire result set, which will eat up a lot of memory for such a large query.

Rather than resetting the index on the resultSet as you do at present - which doesn't clear the cached result, I would suggest you write a query that retrieves the appropriate rows for the given page, and execute that each time the page changes. Thow away the old result set each time to ensure you're not caching anything.

Depending on the database you are using, you would either use the rownum pseudo-column (Oracle), the row_number() (DB2, MSSQL) function or the limit x offset y syntax (MySql).

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your resultSet is not subject for GC in his particular case. Inspect your code and see, where the link to this resultSet really goes so that memory leak occurs.