# Java Heap filling up with JDBC4PreparedStatement

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa, playframework-2.0

I'm running a Play! 2.3 app that is multithreaded using Akka.  Each thread accesses a MySQL database and runs some computations.  Every time I run a set of these tasks, the app's memory footprint increases, largely due to `JDBC4PreparedStatement` objects that never go away.  After a few runs, these objects take up over 200MB, and soon add up to an out of memory error Calling `Sytem.gc()` doesn't lower it at all.

[image]

I'm using Hibernate 4.3.0 for persistence, and calling `clear()` on the `EntityManager` doesn't help either, so it's not that there are persistent objects being stored anywhere.  [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7765735/693542) implies that there may be `Statement` objects being left open somewhere, but I'm never interfacing directly with `Statement` objects or `Connection` objects, just with JPA's `EntityManager`.

**Is this expected behavior for MySQL JDBC or JPA? How can I solve this memory leak?** I'm not sure where to look for solutions, being unsure whether this is issue is due to MySQL or JDBC or JPA or Hibernate's implementation of it.  Or possibly the way Play! handles JPA.

---

EDIT

To be clear, I'm not using `Connection` or `Statement` objects, so there isn't anything for me to close.  Here's an example, where I get the `EntityManager` from Play in a transaction, do something, then the transaction commits.

```
        JPA.withTransaction( () -> {
            Site site= JPA.em().find(Site.class, siteId);
            site.setDomain("www.stackoverflow.com");
        });
```

Comment: Did you check related SE questions like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5664831/java-persistance-memory-leaks and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5675184/java-persistence-memory-leaks?

Comment: Hadn't seen those in particular.  The problem in those was just loading too much into memory at one time, not any kind of leak.  I'm very careful to clear out any persistence cache after I'm done with it.  At this point, I'm even regularly using `EntityManager.clear()`, at cost of speed.

Answer (score 0):

This is expected behavior. You will have to tell the mysql connection to return a cursor instead of the select of the full set by setting:

```
stmt = conn.createStatement(java.sql.ResultSet.TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY,
              java.sql.ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
stmt.setFetchSize(Integer.MIN_VALUE);
```

Your specific settings could be slight different then this based on your requirements, so some fiddling around might be required.

Comment: As I mentioned in the question, I'm not using any `Statement` or `Connection` objects; I'm using the JPA interface. I added an edit to clarify

Comment: You will have to use native JDBC to avoid the JPA behavior in this location.